# Ctypes Structure AutoComplete

Tags: python, ctypes

How is that possible for Python IDE(any) Intellisense to discover structure members in design time?

```
    class MY_STRUCTURE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("member1", c_int),
                    ("member2", c_int)]

         #Any idea declare the fields like self.member1 here inside the structure?

    my_structure = MY_STRUCTURE()
    my_structure.member1 = 0
```

This is O.K in runtime but is there any way for intellisense to detect that there is a member1 inside the my_structure when typing "my_structure." ?

Just for this purpose I create a python wrapper class consist of same member names and equalize/bind them whenever required. However I feel it is a dirty way.

I will distribute a python SDK, if ctypes structure is compiled to bytecode(no source code) then there wont be any idea for the user what is the member of the structures if no extra documentation is provided. This will make both developer and user work more sophisticated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know.  Verbatim taken, the answer is of course "yes", an IDE has such a way to detect that there is a `member1` inside the structure.  Is that what you want to know?

Comment: when you type my_structure. (notice '.'), members are not listed in auto code complete window.

Comment: In my standard cpython installation (terminal, typing just `python`), the completion works just fine and `member1` is proposed along with some dozen others.  So, yes, an IDE can do that as well.  But I'm pretty sure the "yes" is not what you wanted to know.  Please rephrase your question so that we know what you really want to find out.

Comment: @Alfe Thank you, I just confirm autocomplete show members of structures in autocomplete window in python standard IDE. I am using PyCharms Jet Brains and it does not show. I found alternative solution will post it now

Answer (score 1):

I understand from @Alfe response that this depends on the IDE. Python IDLE find the members of the structure in design time. PyCharm cannot.

I use my structure with following way, and looks working fine. By this way ctypes.structure can also be expanded with python class features.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

    class MY_STRUCTURE(ctypes.Structure):
        def __init__(self):
            self.member1 = 1
            self.member2 = 2
            super().__init__(member1=self.member1,
                         member2=self.member2)

        _fields_ = [("member1", c_int),
                    ("member2", c_int)]
```

The key here is to call super() base class.