# PyCharm suggestons/completion with ctypes Structure and Union

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, structure, union, bit-fields

Recently I was looking for a convenient way for defining bit fields in Python that would work similarly to those in C. I need this for registers handling in various HW components but that's less important. 
After some research, I did not find anything that would suit my needs and finally created my own piece of code using ctypes Structure and Union. Below you can see the class definition and usage example.

```
# register class in question
class register():
    def __init__(self, reg_address, reg_fields):
        Reg_fields = type('Reg_fields', (ctypes.Structure,), {"_fields_": reg_fields})
        Reg = type('reg', (ctypes.Union,), {"_fields_": [("f", Reg_fields), ("dword", c_uint32)]})
        self.address = reg_address
        self.val = Reg()

# example class for HW component register set
class HW_component_example:
    def __init__(self, base_addr):
        # example register declaration
        reg_fields = [
            ("ptrn_length", c_uint32, 8),       # bit7..0
            ("bf_length", c_uint32, 8),         # bit15..8
            ("buf_a_addr_clr", c_uint32, 1),    # bit16
            ("buf_b_addr_clr", c_uint32, 1),    # bit17
            ("buf_c_addr_clr", c_uint32, 1),    # bit18
            ("buf_d_addr_clr", c_uint32, 1),    # bit19
            ("reserved", c_uint32, 10),         # bit29..20
            ("dmpr_restart", c_uint32, 1),      # bit30
            ("ce_enable", c_uint32, 1), ]       # bit31
        self.reg1 = register(base_addr + 0x014, reg_fields)

# component declaration
HW_object = HW_component_example(0x00091000)

# usage example - register field access (a chunk of 32bit value)
HW_object.reg1.val.f.bf_length = 16

# usage example - full register value access
HW_object.reg1.val.dword = 0x12345678
```

This work really well and without any hiccups. The problem that I'm facing is actually with PyCharm. It refuses completion of items from structure and union. I found this thread [Ctypes Structure AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576778/ctypes-structure-autocomplete) that states this is a problem in some IDEs including PyCharm and even suggests a solution using the super() method like this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

    class MY_STRUCTURE(ctypes.Structure):
        def __init__(self):
            self.member1 = 1
            self.member2 = 2
            super().__init__(member1=self.member1,
                         member2=self.member2)

        _fields_ = [("member1", c_int),
                    ("member2", c_int)]
```

This is all great but the problem is my class is defined dynamically by an argument "reg_fields". Therefore I do not really have an idea how to combine those two ways of class definition. I'm open to suggestions about other ways to make PyCharm complete those items or even other ways for such bit fields (but only those not requiring bit shifts, masking and all other bit operations mess ;-) )